# update with nested query

Tags: mysql

Below is my query and the associated error. What am I doing wrong?

```
update aaalogin 
  set name = 
      ( select aaacontactinfo.emailid 
        from aaacontactinfo 
        WHERE aaalogin.user_id = aaausercontactinfo.user_id 
          and aaausercontactinfo.contactinfo_id = aaacontactinfo.contactinfo_id
      );
```

I get the

> Error: Unknown column 'aaausercontactinfo.user_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: No idea what that is. Can you elaborate? - im an idiot, i thought you were talking about something with mysql. I will accept the answer when I find one that works.

Comment: i 'll try it tomorrow.Good night

Answer (score 0):

`aaausercontactinfo` is not included in the `FROM` tables list, try with:

```
UPDATE aaalogin SET name =
(
    SELECT aaacontactinfo.emailid
    FROM aaacontactinfo, aaalogin, aaausercontactinfo
    WHERE aaalogin.user_id = aaausercontactinfo.user_id
    AND aaausercontactinfo.contactinfo_id = aaacontactinfo.contactinfo_id
);
```

Comment: Get the error "You can't specify target table 'aaalogin' for update in FROM clause."

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UPDATE aaalogin SET name =
(
    SELECT aaacontactinfo.emailid
    FROM aaacontactinfo, aaausercontactinfo
    WHERE aaalogin.user_id = aaausercontactinfo.user_id
    AND aaausercontactinfo.contactinfo_id = aaacontactinfo.contactinfo_id
);
```

No need for aaalogin in subquery. It even may return multiple records in subquery if used.

Comment: ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '-' for key 'AaaLogin_UK10'

Comment: Seems your name column is unique and subquery returns an existing name '-'